# SSRS showing old data in Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

We have 1 report that's being exported to PDF manually in the web page.

However, when we update a certain value, the new value can be seen in the table but when we tried exporting the data, it keep showing the old value in the report.

The stored procedure used in the report is showing the new value.

It works fine when running the VS 2013.

I am not sure if caching is enabled in our report server but in that RDL file, we did not explicitly specify to cached the data as shown below.

[Processing Options Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31O3z.png)

[Snapshot Options Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHQWX.png)

[Parameter Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGg1D.png)

There are no RDL.Data files in the report server as well and other reports are extracted to PDF and its working fine.

Do you have any idea or did I missed something that needs to be checked?

Thank you.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it pertained to report caching during development. If you have verified the data then I would ensure your report is pulling its data from the correct database. I would also look into your report caching options server side.

Comment: Hi Ross. I have attached the screenshot of caching options in the report server side. I am not sure if that's what you are referring to. Thank you.